React Native - Creating a Sign for my App Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
I keep getting this error, i typed in the password correctly:
PS C:\Users\tp_re\source\repos\poller\pollit> java -jar c:\pepk.jar --keystore=pollit.keystore --alias=pollit --output=pollit.zip --include-cert --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem
Enter password for store 'pollit.keystore':
Enter password for key 'pollit':
Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting 
RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:574)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.encryptPrivateKeyWithCkmRsaAesKeyWrapEncryption(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:284)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:213)       
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:165)      
PS C:\Users\tp_re\source\repos\poller\pollit>

Both passwords entered for pollit.keystore and pollit are the same
